# TBB equivalants in C++11

Tags: c++11, tbb

I got an old codebase, where I want to use some implementations in a new environment. The old base used the TBB framework which I am really unfamiliar with.

Are there any equivalents implementaions to these TBB's types in C++11:

- tbb::enumerable_thread_specific<...>
- mutex_t
- mutex_t::scoped_lock

If not: Any tips how I can convert them (links to good TBB summaries, tutorials, ...) or do I need to work myself into the whole TBB documentation?

(And no. Inserting TBB to the project is not an option.)

EDIT: forget to mention tbb::this_tbb_thread::yield  any suggestion about this?

Comment: I would suggest making the old codebase work first and only then change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TBB features in your code do have near-equivalents in C++11 (or you can create one simply).

1. [`enumerable_thread_specific<T>`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468088) is an implementation of thread-local storage.  It can use the platform's local storage, or a [`tbb::concurrent_vector`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506203) to hold instances.  The default is to consume no platform thread-local storage keys.  C++11 has the [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) qualifier, so depending on how the `enumerable_thread_specific` is used you can replace it with a `thread_local` version of the same type.  If you are using the structure to persist the data, or to access it outside a thread-local context, you may have your work cut out for you.
2. `mutex_t` is a generic mutex type, and can be replaced with `std::mutex`, though the developer may have [chosen a particular implementation](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Mutex_Flavors.html) (like `spin_mutex`) that will be affected by the replacement.
3. `scoped_lock` is an [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) object that locks the mutex on construction, and when the leaving the scope will unlock the mutex (making it somewhat exception-friendly.)  You can use [`std::lock_guard<std::mutex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) if you're at C++17, otherwise you can roll your own.
4. It has been awhile since I read the yield documentation.  I believe the implementation looks for other possible tasks before giving up the time slice.  You can use [`std::this_thread::yield()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) to relenquish the time slice, but the behavior may differ if the code is using TBB constructs.  The fact you haven't mentioned any other TBB stuff implies to me there are none in the program, and the `tbb::yield()` does the same thing as `std::this_thread::yield()`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Unfortunately, they used spin_mutex and it affects the code because now a specific page size is exceeded. Do you know any replacement for spin_mutex?

Comment: The family of mutexes all have the same basic property (mutual exclusion.)  The difference is performance; spin_mutex is fastet, unfair and hogs CPU.

I am not sure why it would cause a problem with page size, unless it is a member of a class. The mutexes are memory-aligned so they have the best performance (a 4-byte mutex aligned on a 2-byte boundary would require a lot of "finagling" to get it to work.)  Is the mutex part of a class?  If so, look at the class offsets; maybe you can shuffle the members to minimize alignment space required.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making the old codebase work first and only then change.

[`tbb::enumerable_thread_specific<...>`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468088) does not have standard equivalents.

`mutex_t` and `mutex_t::scoped_lock` you can replace with [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and [`std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock).

Comment: Thank you. The oldcodebase is working on the old system. Any suggestions how to translate the thread type? (:

Comment: btw: forgot to mention tbb::this_tbb_thread::yield. any suggestion about this one?

Comment: @Herget hint: the standard library prefixes things with `std` and there's a place called google where you can type things like `std::yield` and it'll tell you if such a thing exists.

Comment: @kfsone yes I heard of this place. Should be great for finding things. But my problem is that I don't know the TBB framework and if it has some special implementation which the std version does not have. I think there are reasons why the original developers used it and not because it looks more beautiful ;)

Comment: @Nicol Bolas yeah seems like that... Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Herget TBB is a fine library. People used it because it provides atomics and syncronization primitives in the days before C++11 equivalents were available. It also provides the task manager, thread-safe containers and other components that do not have standard equivalents.